# Using Custom View in IB

Tags: ios, objective-c, loading, iboutlet, custom-view

I have a Custom View I created that should appear in several View Controllers in the App.

So... I've created a subview of UIView with xib, h and m files for it (and set the View in the xib file with the Class), added my UIs to the view xib file and connected them as IBOutlets:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Then... I added 2 UIViews to a View Controller, set their Class to MYCustomView and connected IBOutlets of that type to the VC:

[image]

[image]

[image]

And... it doesn't work...

Now... I'm familiar with the technique of loading the xib using the NSBundle loadNibNamed:owner:options: method.

But... I would really like to be able to set the instances of MYCustomView in IB directly (constraints, sizing, etc...).

Is there another way to do this? Or should I just create 'placeholder' UIViews and add my instances of MYCustomView as their subviews?

Answer (score 2):

There is some UIView category that I always use for custom views, you can use it yourself with few easy steps:

Click command + N to add a new Objective-C category.
In the header file add those lines:

```
// This category let the UIView that using it to load a XIB with the same name as the UIView.h & .m files easily.
// See: MyContentWaitingSong custom view for reference.
@interface UIView (NibLoading)

+ (id)loadInstanceFromNib;

@end
```

Than in your .m file add those lines:

```
// This category let the UIView that using it to load a XIB with the same name as the UIView.h & .m files easily.
// See: MyContentWaitingSong custom view for reference.
@implementation UIView (NibLoading)

+ (id)loadInstanceFromNib
{
    UIView *result = nil;

    NSArray* elements = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:nil options:nil];

    for (id anObject in elements) {
        if ([anObject isKindOfClass:[self class]]) {
            result = anObject;
            break;
        }
    }

    return result;
}

@end
```

Than you can use it in your custom view class, just import the category and implement an init method like this one:

```
- (id)init
{
    self = [YourCustomClassName loadInstanceFromNib];
    if (self)
    {
        //    Your initial implementation
    }
    return self;
}
```

Than your implementation should look like that:

```
YourCustomClassName *someName = [[YourCustomClassName alloc] init];
someName.frame = frame;
[self.view addSubView:someName];
```

Good luck.

Comment: Nice answer, I use something like this (but a bit more complex). The only thing is that that's the answer to a different question.

Answer (score 1):

No, you a asking about referencing nibs from other nibs. There are ways to achieve this with some `awakeAfterUsingCoder:` hacks or something like that. Usually you check if view has no subviews and load view from nib then or create some IB-dummy class that replaces itself with target class after it get's loaded. All this techniques have issues, so I'd recommend against them.

So **I'd suggest loading it from code**, nice catch would be to use view controller containment.

There's something really cool, appeared relatively not long ago: [IBDesignable and IBInspectable](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-IB_objects_media/chapters/CreatingaLiveViewofaCustomObject.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014224-CH41-SW1), it had to appear at some point.

One example would be some temporary code I used while required framework was not yet ready (It's an UIButton dummy IB subclass):

```
//
// That's just an example, do not use it in production code
//
- (id)awakeAfterUsingCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    UIButton *buttonMain = // create button, which will replace button of dummy class from nib
    buttonMain.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

    // copy internal constraints
    [self copyInternalConstraintsToView:buttonMain];

    // set titles
    NSString *title = [self titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [buttonMain setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    title = [self titleForState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [buttonMain setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    title = [self titleForState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [buttonMain setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateDisabled];

    title = [self titleForState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [buttonMain setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateSelected];

    return buttonMain;
}

/**
 *  Used only in awakeAfterUsingCoder, as self has only internal constraints at that moment.
 *  If you'll try to use it somewhere else, behavior is undefined.
 *
 *  This method is straightforward and could not suit everybody's needs.
 *
 *  %Comments edited%
 *
 *  @param replacementView view to add constraints to
 */
- (void)copyInternalConstraintsToView:(UIView *)replacementView
{
    for (NSLayoutConstraint* constraint in self.constraints)
    {
        if([constraint isMemberOfClass:[NSLayoutConstraint class]])
        {
            id first = constraint.firstItem;
            id second = constraint.secondItem;
            id newFirst = first;
            id newSecond = second;

            BOOL match = NO;
            if (first == self)
            {
                newFirst = replacementView;
                match = YES;
            }
            if (second == self)
            {
                newSecond = replacementView;
                match = YES;
            }


            // constraints to subviews from recource are not supported
            if(newFirst != nil && newFirst != replacementView)
            {
                match = NO;
            }

            if(newSecond != nil && newSecond != replacementView)
            {
                match = NO;
            }

            if (match)
            {
                @try
                {
                    NSLayoutConstraint* newConstraint = nil;
                    newConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:newFirst
                                                                 attribute:constraint.firstAttribute
                                                                 relatedBy:constraint.relation
                                                                    toItem:newSecond
                                                                 attribute:constraint.secondAttribute
                                                                multiplier:constraint.multiplier
                                                                  constant:constraint.constant];
                    newConstraint.shouldBeArchived = constraint.shouldBeArchived;
                    newConstraint.priority = constraint.priority;

                    [replacementView addConstraint:newConstraint];
                }
                @catch (NSException *exception)
                {
                    NSLog(@"Constraint exception: %@\nFor constraint: %@", exception, constraint);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Some links:
[Embedding custom-view Nibs in another Nib: Towards the holy grail](https://blog.compeople.eu/apps/?p=142), [An Update on Nested Nib Loading](http://blog.yangmeyer.de/blog/2012/07/09/an-update-on-nested-nib-loading)

Answer (score 1):

Well I think there are two possible approaches for that:

1. As you mentioned use the technique with `loadNibNamed:owner:options`
2. If you are using Storyboards you can use so called *container views*. Just style your custom view within the storyboard, connect it by using a segue and you are almost done.

For the second approach you need to use a view controller to put in your custom view, but this should't be a problem at all. In my opinion it is even better to use a separate view controller to put in your view controller logic.